# Remove a referral from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My website has a feature to login via Google. So whenever they log in via Google, in my Google Analytics it counts'accounts.google.com' as a referral. Is there any way to prevent this from going to 'referral'?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have yo use the referal exclusion list, this prevent the session cutting and avoid the creation of new sessions when the user return from account.google.com, but if the domain is google.cm make sure to use the correct domain (you dont want to mess the Organic and SEM data).

To exclude you have to go to the property tab and them referral exclusion list
[image]

And them add the domain[image]

This change is not retroactive, that means if the user got this referral as campaign you have to wait until this expire on the server, bu default this is 30 days. So can you see remnants during that date range.

Comment: I've done this. But still I'm seeing referrals from accounts.google.com

Comment: Hi @GijoVarghes, on my cases neither :/ , i'm working with this in a couple of accounts, and it's not working in some of them ( on the recent ones). Now i excluded only the domain to see if this exlcusion is only based on domains (and if i put a subdomain is treated this as domain).  I'll give some time to see if the new update are applied to the new data

Comment: I'm back with this, i've asked to google and they confirm that the session information is stored on the server after the exclusion, so you have to wait until the expiration of the campaign information. By default this can be on the domain during 31 days

Answer (score 0):

You have set it up already, only thing I would do is escape the dots
**accounts\.google\.com**

You can Verify the filter before saving.
[image: ga-verify-filter]

If there is significant difference in data it will show message otherwise you get this

*This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small.*

This message means that filter is not significant enough to improve data or set up incorrectly. You may have to play a little with it to get to right result.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey it's a bad idea to exclude this, the only result on this is delete it, this will not avoid the session cut, only lost the source

Comment: @KemenPaulosPlaza Not sure what do you mean _by this will not avoid the session cut, only lost the source_
Exclude will remove session count, not just source if you mean that. 
This is what I understand from  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en

Comment: Apply that filter will only remove the referal as string, so when you see the report you will see "" as referral (or not set,i need to verify),you still create  a new session with strange data.

In the past, i've tryed to do the same but with the source and medium and the result was get (not set)/(not set) as source medium. And polluted data everywhere

Comment: If I read correctly https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034842?hl=en it says _Filtering domain referrals is different from the Property level referral exclusion feature. Filters remove the hits from your traffic stream, so no sessions from those hits will be recorded. Referral exclusion, on the other hand, treats hits that are referred from the excluded sources as direct traffic._ 
Another post http://help.analyticsedge.com/spam-filter/why-you-should-not-use-the-referral-exclusion-list-for-spam/ reiterates the same theory.

Comment: @Sandeep I've already tried that. But its not working. That's why

Comment: When you say its not working does it exclude all google.com referrals or it does not remove account.google.com?
Another thing I would try is pattern match * at the end to account for any thing following accounts.google.com

Comment: @sandeep you're right, i don't know why i saw  find and replace, yes, this will exclude all the data from that source, so this sessions will be not on the report. I'm not sure if this is the desired behaviour . But this is a option